# What is the difference between '$$directoryName' and '$(directoryName)' in makefile

Tags: makefile, autotools

I have two makefiles

The first :

```
dir = ../dir1
dis = ../dir2
test:
    $(MAKE) -C $(dir)
```

The second one :

```
DIRS = dir1 dir2 dir3

test:
    for dir in $(DIRS); do \
            if $(MAKE)  -C $$dir ; then \
                true; \
            else \
                exit 1; \
            fi; \
    done
```

Why in the for loop I need $$dir when in a simple recipe I have to write $(dir)

Another question:
I have this other makefile, in which I have this other for loop:

```
all clean dep depend print:
for dir in $(DIRS); do \
    if $(MAKE) $(MAKE_FLAGS) -C $$dir $@; then \
        true; \
    else \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
done
```

What is the meaning of $@ in the line

```
if $(MAKE) $(MAKE_FLAGS) -C $$dir $@; then \
```

I know this is an Automatic Variable that matches the file name of the target of the rule.
Here the target appears to be a command like cancel:

```
cancell:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Comment: This is two questions -- please split the second part into a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is a makefile variable the other is a shell variable.   `$(directoryName)` will be resolved by make, as it's reading.   For `$$directoryName`, make converts the `$$` to `$`, and passes that to the shell (so `$$directoryName` becomes`$directoryName`).  The shell expands it to whatever it has in its environment.

A bit more detail:

If, in make, you define (outside of any recipe)

```
var := 1
```

then `var` is a make variable.   If you then call

```
all:
    echo $(var)
```

Then make expands the recipe to `echo ../dir1` *before* passing the command to the shell.   If, on the other hand, you do:

```
all:
    var=1; echo $$var
```

Then make passes `var=1; echo $var` to the shell.   The shell sets `var` to `1`, and then prints it.   Notice if you tried:

```
all:
    var=1;
    echo $$var
```

Then the recipe will not print anything -- that's because the first line is run in a shell, which sets `var` to `1`, but then exits.   The next line runs, which passes `echo $var` in a new shell, but this shell doesn't know what `var` was set to in the previous shell.

In addition, if you run `var=1;make`, then make will set a makefile variable `var` to be `1` when it starts.  Thus a `$(info $(var))` will show 1, in this case.

For syntax, in make you can do `var := 1` (with spaces).  In bash you cannot add spaces.   In bash, `$var` refers to the variable var.  In make `$var` refers to `$v` followed by the literal `ar`.   (In make you *have* to use either `{}` or `()` to refer to multicharacter variables).   In bash, you can either use `{}`, or no braces (`$(var)` has a different meaning in bash).

make also has two [flavors](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) of variables, one defined with `:=` and one with `=`.